# Android FileObserver onEvent doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

FileObserver in my app returns message "Service started" at the top of the void but doesn't return message "check" from onEvent when I create or delete specified file. I have TextView at MainActivity which showing the size of this file so I'm sure that I specified path correctly.

```
private void startWatching() {

    final String pathToWatch = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/check/viber_data";
    File file = new File(Uri.parse(pathToFile).getPath());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started " + pathToWatch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    observer = new FileObserver(file, FileObserver.DELETE + FileObserver.CREATE) {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, String s) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching();
}
```

Comment: I would not be surprised if this failed to work on Android 11+, due to the way that external storage access has changed.